# Newtonsoft.Json Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: リ

Tags: c#

I need to deserialize this JSON data:

```
{
    illustId: 73024242,
    illustTitle: 标题,
    illustType: 0,
    tags: [
        ロリ,
        猫耳
    ],
    userId: 123,
    userName: 庭,
    userImage: null,
    isBookmarkable: true,
    isBookmarked: false,
    isPrivateBookmark: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 1536,
    pageCount: 3,
    bookmarkCount: 0,
    responseCount: 0
}
```

Here is my class definition:

```
[JsonObject]
public class JsonItem
{
    [JsonProperty("illustId")]
    public int PicID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("illustTitle")]
    public string TitleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("illustType")]
    private int Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string PicURL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public object Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userImage")]
    private object userImage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isBookmarkable")]
    private bool orzA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isBookmarked")]
    private bool orzB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isPrivateBookmark")]
    private bool orzC { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("width")]
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageCount")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bookmarkCount")]
    private int orzD { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responseCount")]
    private int orzE { get; set; }
}
```

I'm running this code:

```
dynamic jsonText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried to use UTF-8 charset too.

this is StackTrace
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader reader)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   在 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value)
   在 Test.Program.Main() 位置 H:\爬虫\Test\Test\Program.cs:行号 34

Comment: So the strings aren’t inside quotes? That’s invalid JSON

Answer (score -1):

The solution to the error is @Sami Kuhmonen's comment, Enclose string in quotation marks.
Please let me add this information.

---

This code does not use the JsonItem class.

```
dynamic jsonText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
```

To deserialize Json to JsonItem, use type parameters as follows:

```
JsonItem jsonText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonItem>(str);
```